# Push back string into vector<T>

Tags: c++, templates

I'm finally trying to learn templates and I created a template function that will return an `std::vector` with a generic type.

When compiling I get an error:

> error: no matching function for call to
> ‘std::vector::push_back(std::string&)’

Is there a way to support `std::string` or a comparable type in the template vector in addition to the primitive types?

Here is a 'Minimal, Reproducible Example' that doesn't compile due to this error (this is obviously not my code, it just illustrates the error):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum types{
    TINT = 0,
    TDOUBLE = 1,
    TSTRING = 2,
};

class TestClass{
    public:

    template<typename T> std::vector<T> getData(types type)
        {
            std::vector<T> entries;

            int i_value;
            double d_value;
            std::string st_value;

            switch (type)
            {
                case types::TINT:
                    i_value = 1;
                    entries.push_back(i_value);
                    break;
                case types::TDOUBLE:
                    d_value = 0.1;
                    entries.push_back(d_value);
                    break;
                case types::TSTRING:
                    st_value = "foo";
                    entries.push_back(st_value); //Pushing an std::string causes a compile error
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        return entries;
    }
};

int main()
{
    TestClass bar;
    std::vector<int> test = bar.getData<int>(types::TINT);

    return 0;
}
```

Commenting the line `entries.push_back(st_value);` makes everything compile again.

Comment: Calling `getData<int>` means `entries` will be a `std::vector<int>`, and therefore you cannot put a `std::string` in it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `types` argument? This will never work if the user mismatches it with the template type parameter, making it a very questionable idea in the first place

Comment: templates dont work like that, all branches of the switch must compile even if they are never taken. You can use `if constexpr` though

Comment: Be sure to `#include <string>` where you use it.

Comment: @UnholySheep because, as i stated in the question, this is just a minimal reproducible example. If I hadn't put it probably someone would have complained about how can I choose to put an int or a string there. Is it easier to include the library that implements the getter functions and make the example super long or write `d_value = 0.1` and just make a `Minimal` example that shows the same question I have?

Comment: But the `types` argument doesn't work. The way to choose what to put in would be done via the template type argument (as e.g.: in VLL's answer).

Comment: @UnholySheep as I said, it was just faster to write it like this and I didn't really think much about it since that wasn't the core of the question but only to have a way to differentiate the `int`, `double` and `string` paths and make the example compile

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number oh ok got it, I actually didn't know that the compiler would expand the function to be `std::vector<int> getData`. Now I can see that obviously that wouldn't compile with an `std::string`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code does not compile because you try to check the types at runtime. This is too late. Use [`std::is_same`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to make a compile time check.

```
template<typename T> std::vector<T> getData()
{
    std::vector<T> entries;

    int i_value;
    double d_value;
    std::string st_value;

    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>) {
        i_value = 1;
        entries.push_back(i_value);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, double>) { 
        d_value = 0.1;
        entries.push_back(d_value);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::string>) {
        st_value = "foo";
        entries.push_back(st_value);
    }
    return entries;
}
```

Comment: To add: You can also call `push_back("foo")` directly and avoid having a bunch of local variables for each type.

Comment: @perivesta Correct. I assumed there was a reason to have the local variables in the example.

Comment: @VLL yeah the local variables are just something that remained from the original code and I just left them there when creating the example

Answer (score 2):

This line `std::vector<int> test = bar.getData<int>(types::TINT);` 
caused the compiler to expand the function to be:

```
    // Note: T becomes int
    std::vector<int> getData(types type)
        {
           // Note: T becomes int
            std::vector<int> entries;

            int i_value;
            double d_value;
            std::string st_value;

            switch (type)
            {
                case types::TINT:
                    i_value = 1;
                    entries.push_back(i_value);
                    break;
                case types::TDOUBLE:
                    d_value = 0.1;
                    entries.push_back(d_value);
                    break;
                case types::TSTRING:
                    st_value = "foo";
                    entries.push_back(st_value); //Pushing an std::string causes a compile error
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        return entries;
    }
```

Which means, `entries` is a vector of integers. It cannot take a `std::string` object.

Comment: Oh now I get it, so if I understand correctly commenting `entries.push_back(st_value)` makes the program compile not because the others are primitive types but because the `double` would be implicitly converted to `int` if that `case` would be entered but this obviously can't happen with `std::string` right?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Some compilers (or some certain versions) may complain, but some will implicitly convert `double` to `int`.